# Fillable fields vanish from PDF form when include'd in another PDF

Tags: hyperref, pdfpages, forms

I have created, using hyperref, a set of fillable PDF forms. When I open the PDFs in Adobe Acrobat Reader, the forms work as expected (these are simple no-frills forms without any JavaScript - one of those fill-it-in-and-print-it-out varieties).

However, when I try to include these forms in a larger LaTeX document (where these will be present in the Appendices), using (pdfpages):

```
\includepdf[pages={-}]{Form1.pdf}
```

and pdflatex that larger document, I just get the static text fields in the appendix - the fillable part of the form is gone!

I wish to retain the PDF form as is (which I thought was how pdfpages worked). What are my options (if I am not missing something rather simple)?

Is there an alternative to pdfpages here?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that is how `pdfpages` works.  See the last paragraph before section two.  I believe it relies on `graphicx`, which suggests to me that it is simply (to use an unfair adverb) inserting an "image" in a clever way.

Comment: I think, that `pdfpages` includes the files as `flat`, i.e. without any further PDF feature, just like a graphics file.

Comment: Any non-pdfpages solution?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer : I think you are right. I just made a quick test, and when embedding with pdfpages a pdf with links, they disappear. I was'nt aware of this lack.

Comment: @user2751530 : if this form was generated by LaTeX, why could'nt you include its source code in your larger document? Did you consider the [`standalone`](http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone) package?

Comment: @Clément: The problem is, that there mustn't not be more than **one** `\begin{Form}...\end{Form}` in a document. It is not possible to combine multiple separate forms, unfortunately

Comment: @user275130: The only way is to use one giant `\begin{Form}...\end{Form}` with multiple pages and place your elements there, but this will probably mean to rename the elements ids... (well, I have not done this for a long time now)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have multiple \begin{Form}...\end{Form} blocks. I know its not "permitted" in hyperref, and since it did not seem to affect me, I was wondering when it might come back to bite me in the ass. I guess this is one example. One question though - why would doing this prevent pdfpages from flattening the document? Or are you referring to the standalone package?

Comment: @user2751530: I did not say that multiple Form environments will prevent flattening. I wrote `one giant`... environment, which is logically sectioned into multiple 'pages', either for print or for for screen usage. In this case, all field elements should work anyway and they are not flattened at all.

Comment: @user31729 Some workarounds are mentioned at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194958/includepdf-combined-pdf-highlights-missing