# \includepdf combined pdf highlights missing

Tags: pdfpages

I used `\includepdf[pages=-]{...}` to combine several pdf files. It does combine, but some highlights made in some individual pdfs using Adobe Reader Comments are missing. The highlights can be seen in individual pdfs, but not the combined one.

Any solution? Many thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by “highlights”?

Comment: metadata such as comments, links or highlights are not transferred to the new pfd by `pdfpages`.

Comment: These will always be lost. There is a technical explanation on here somewhere, but I have forgotten where. The PDFs are treated as images and the meta data and links are not *image* data as such and is thus ignored by the image driver.

Comment: highlight is a tool in comments, just like highlighting text using a marker pen. So does it mean that there is no solution to this? Or I need to convert the combination of these to a single image?

Answer (score 15):

There is a very simple work around to this problem: just print the pdf document using a pdf printer e.g. Adobe and choose to include the markings. When you include this new pdf document the markings will be visible in the final output.

Comment: Quick, easy, gets the job done perfectly. Love it! Thanks

Comment: there is also a builtin feature in adobe arobat that lets you do this: https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/how-to-flatten-in-adobe-acrobat-pro-dc/td-p/7986866?page=1

Answer (score 9):

In the [documentation of pdfpages](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf) you find on page 2:

> *Links and other interactive features of PDF documents*
>
> When including pages of a PDF only the so called content stream of these pages is copied but no links. Up to now there are no TeX-engines (pdfTeX, XeTeX, . . . ) available that can copy links or other interactive features of a PDF document, too
>
> Thus, all kinds of links(1) will get lost during inclusion. 
>   ....
>
> (1) Actually not only links but all kinds of PDF annotations will get lost.

So the feature you need is not supported.

The documentation continues with:

> However, there’s a glimmer of hope. Some links may be extracted and later
>   reinserted by a package called pax which can be downloaded from CTAN [3]. Have
>   a look at it!

You find the [pax-packages on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pax). It is (November 2016) in status ex­per­i­men­tal and the last update was 2011. (I haven't tried it myself).

Comment: A full example constructing conference proceedings using pax is available at https://github.com/gi-ev/LNI-proceedings.